# removeChild for a map (mapQuest)

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to close the map when the user clicks on the "Back" button.

I'm using AS3 for Adobe AIR app.

I've tried to call a function with removeChild(MyMap) in order to close it, but it's not working (Error #2025:  the supplied displayobject must be a child of the caller).

Do you know how I can do it ?

Here's my code :

```
var MyMap:TileMap = new TileMap("KEY_OF_MAP");
addChild(MyMap);

VisibleButton();

}        

function VisibleButton():void
{
    var skip:MovieClip;
    skip = new skype
    addChild(skip);
    skip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeMap, false, 0, true);
}

function closeMap(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("ferme carte");
    var MyMap:TileMap = new TileMap("KEY_OF_MAP");
    removeChild(MyMap);
}
```

---

**EDIT :**

So, I'll give you the maximum details as possible.

I've put directly the code into the scenario like this : [image]

At the 11th image I've code a button named "goMapButton". 
The action code is :

```
goMapButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callDisplayMap, false, 0, true);

function callDisplayMap(event:MouseEvent):void{
    displayMap();
}
```

In my 12th image I've got this action code :

```
stop();

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import com.mapquest.tilemap.*;
    import com.mapquest.LatLng;
    import com.mapquest.tilemap.pois.*;
    import com.mapquest.services.directions.Directions;
import com.mapquest.services.directions.DirectionsConstants;
import com.mapquest.services.directions.DirectionsEvent;
import com.mapquest.services.geocode.Geocoder;
import com.mapquest.services.geocode.*;
import com.mapquest.services.geocode.GeocoderEvent;
import com.mapquest.services.geocode.GeocoderLocation;
import com.mapquest.tilemap.Size;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import com.mapquest.tilemap.TileMap;
import com.mapquest.tilemap.controls.inputdevice.MouseWheelZoomControl;
import com.mapquest.tilemap.controls.shadymeadow.SMLargeZoomControl;
 import com.mapquest.tilemap.controls.shadymeadow.SMViewControl;




function displayMap():void{
    trace("displaying Map");
            //turn scaling off
            this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

            // create a new TileMap object, passing your platform key



            var myMap:TileMap = new TileMap("Fmjtd%7Cluur2g0an0%2C2s%3Do5-9azwdr");

                        myMap.size = new Size(800, 533);
            myMap.addControl(new SMLargeZoomControl());
            myMap.addControl(new MouseWheelZoomControl());
            myMap.setCenter(new LatLng(-21.060478, 164.861113),12);     



            //add the map to the sprite.
            addChild(myMap);

var myPoi:Poi;
                  //ICONES BATTERIES
             [Embed (source="huiles.png")] 
            var HuilesImg:Class;
            var embeddedIconPoi:Poi;

              var myIcon:MapIcon = new MapIcon();

                myIcon.setImage(new HuilesImg(),22,32);
              embeddedIconPoi = new Poi(new LatLng(-11.71199, 12.647725));
              embeddedIconPoi.rolloverAndInfoTitleText = "Info about that place";
              embeddedIconPoi.icon = myIcon;
              myMap.addShape(embeddedIconPoi);

VisibleButton();

          }      

//This function makes a button visible at the left corner of the screen
function VisibleButton():void{
              var skip:MovieClip;
              skip = new skype
              addChild(skip);
              skip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeMap, false, 0, true);

          }

//I'd like to close the map when the user click on the skip button

          function closeMap(e:MouseEvent):void{
              var myMap:TileMap = new TileMap("Fmjtd%7Cluur2g0an0%2C2s%3Do5-9azwdr");
              trace("ferme carte");
              trace(myMap.parent == null);


          }
```

Comment: try removing the MyMap with MyMap.parent.removeChild(MyMap); If it works fine - in your non-working code you try to remove MyMap from a different place from the one you've added it to.

Comment: I've got the Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.”

Comment: trace(MyMap.parent == null); if it returns true - it doesn't have a parent and thus you need to look in another place. If it prints "false" then there's something strange in your code and it's not visible in the part of program you've posted.

Comment: it returns, indeed, true... So what should I do ?

Comment: I think I should create a container but I'm not very familiar with this... What do you think of that : `var myMap:TileMap = new TileMap("MY_KEY");
 myMap.size = new Size(800, 533);
             myMap.addControl(new SMLargeZoomControl());
             myMap.addControl(new MouseWheelZoomControl());
             myMap.setCenter(new LatLng(48.8566140, 2.3522219),12);
     
 
     var mapContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
    mapContainer.addChild(myMap);`

Comment: Sorry, but there's just not enough code to understand what's wrong. I can guess 5 or 6 possible causes, but I'm not that wouldn't be an answer. You should probably include: info what type of sub-class MyMap is (e.g Sprite, EventDispatcher etc). Or even write the whole chain of inheritance. 2) Post your class code where you create all this, I have a feeling something earlier in your code could be the cause.

Comment: Ok, I've eddited my original post with all the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all remove:

```
var MyMap:TileMap = new TileMap("KEY_OF_MAP");
```

from the closeMap function because you all ready initiated the instance of map in first row of code.

i don't think you will need it after first fix, but if you still getting error you can use this one instead.

```
MyMap.parent.removeChild(MyMap);
```

Like this:

```
stop();

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import com.mapquest.tilemap.*;
    import com.mapquest.LatLng;
    import com.mapquest.tilemap.pois.*;
    import com.mapquest.services.directions.Directions;
import com.mapquest.services.directions.DirectionsConstants;
import com.mapquest.services.directions.DirectionsEvent;
import com.mapquest.services.geocode.Geocoder;
import com.mapquest.services.geocode.*;
import com.mapquest.services.geocode.GeocoderEvent;
import com.mapquest.services.geocode.GeocoderLocation;
import com.mapquest.tilemap.Size;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import com.mapquest.tilemap.TileMap;
import com.mapquest.tilemap.controls.inputdevice.MouseWheelZoomControl;
import com.mapquest.tilemap.controls.shadymeadow.SMLargeZoomControl;
 import com.mapquest.tilemap.controls.shadymeadow.SMViewControl;

// create a new TileMap object, passing your platform key
 var myMap:TileMap = new TileMap("Fmjtd%7Cluur2g0an0%2C2s%3Do5-9azwdr");

function displayMap():void{
    trace("displaying Map");
            //turn scaling off
            this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;







                        myMap.size = new Size(800, 533);
            myMap.addControl(new SMLargeZoomControl());
            myMap.addControl(new MouseWheelZoomControl());
            myMap.setCenter(new LatLng(-21.060478, 164.861113),12);     



            //add the map to the sprite.
            addChild(myMap);

var myPoi:Poi;
                  //ICONES BATTERIES
             [Embed (source="huiles.png")] 
            var HuilesImg:Class;
            var embeddedIconPoi:Poi;

              var myIcon:MapIcon = new MapIcon();

                myIcon.setImage(new HuilesImg(),22,32);
              embeddedIconPoi = new Poi(new LatLng(-11.71199, 12.647725));
              embeddedIconPoi.rolloverAndInfoTitleText = "Info about that place";
              embeddedIconPoi.icon = myIcon;
              myMap.addShape(embeddedIconPoi);

VisibleButton();

          }      

//This function makes a button visible at the left corner of the screen
function VisibleButton():void{
              var skip:MovieClip;
              skip = new skype
              addChild(skip);
              skip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeMap, false, 0, true);

          }

//I'd like to close the map when the user click on the skip button

          function closeMap(e:MouseEvent):void{

              trace("ferme carte");
              trace(myMap.parent == null);

              if (myMap.parent == this)
              {
                   removeChild(myMap);
              }
          }
```

Comment: Yes but if I remove var MyMap  I've got the error : Error #1009: cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Comment: The problem is that you trying to remove object not from objects parent. so you losing reference to object.

Try to take out:
var myMap:TileMap = new TileMap("Fmjtd%7Cluur2g0an0%2C2s%3Do5-9azwdr");  
from displayMap function and put it before function, so myMap Object will be visible to displayMap and closeMap function and you will be sure that is the same one object.

Comment: @user2421975 make sure to mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem